# How to format curl --data argument to match jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, web-scraping

A website has the following function that it uses to retrieve information:

```
function show_best_matches(sequence_id, version_id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://unite.ut.ee/show_best_matches.php',
        data:{
            sequence_id: sequence_id,
            version_id: version_id,
        },
        success:function(html) {
            document.getElementById("best_matches").innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
}
```

I want to use curl to retrieve these data. I have all of the right inputs (sequence IDs and version IDs), but I don't think I'm formatting the --data argument to curl properly. Here's what I've tried (based on other stackoverflow searches):

```
curl -d "sequence_id=56719" -d "version_id=7" -X GET --url https://unite.ut.ee/show_best_matches.php
```

Thanks for any help. If curl isn't the right tool to be using here, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: After some more searching I've tried

`{"sequence_id": "56719", "version_id": "7"}`

but it also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is this:

```
https://unite.ut.ee/show_best_matches.php?sequence_id=56719&version_id=7
```

Turns out you don't use the --data part of curl with GET, you just add the arguments to the end of the URL. First arg is preceded with a ?, and remaining args are delimited with &.

Comment: If you're on Linux, I recommend putting the URL in quotes. Otherwise the terminal will interpret it as two separate commands and will attempt to run the first one in the background : "https://unite.ut.ee/show_best_matches.php?sequence_id=56719&" and "version_id=7"